# Google App Engine Python ImportError Module Not Found

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using Pydev 1.5.9 and the latest version of google app engine, developing in eclipse 3.6

I've set up my environment, and I have my base code executing fine.

Now I'm trying to import the simplejson library using
import simplejson

I've tried

1. adding the simplejson folder to a
   "pydev source folder" within eclipse
2. tried adding simplejson folder as
   an external library
3. tried adding simplejson in PYTHONPATH

I am still encountering an error when I attempt to run using SDK dev server.
'    import simplejson
ImportError: No module named simplejson'

What is the best way to import external libraries into a Python App Engine project using Eclipse and Pydev?

Comment: What exact error message are you seeing?

Comment: import simplejson
ImportError: No module named simplejson

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help with the Google App Engine, and may be too late, but the breadcrumb trail might help someone.

I had a similar problem in pydev and the solution was quite simple.  Here is the [pydev doc](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#id6) which talks about the subject of imports and configuring the interpreter in pydev.

The bit that I had missed, and caused a few hours of frustration, was that I had to press the Apply button in the Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python.  This causes pydev to rebuild its internal indices and if you have added the libary into your PYTHONPATH somewhere (I just dropped it into the python/Lib folder) it should resolve your import problem - it did mine in any case.

Make sure you have automatic builds switched on for your project or rebuild your project if not.

HTH